# how to web scrape hidden text within accordion Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have written a simple script that returns specific information from an Australian Gambling site.

It works well, however I'm having a lot of trouble automating opening each of the accordion drop downs. My script is as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path =r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NBA")

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/sport-competition-component/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/event-list/div[1]/event/div/header/div[1]/h2/a""").click()
time.sleep(2)


posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    with open('output.xls',mode ='a') as f:
        f.write(post.text)
        f.write('\n')

driver.quit()
```

the script prints all the visible text contained within the Class name "market".

output as follows:

```
HEAD TO HEAD
Brooklyn Nets
1.29
Atlanta Hawks
3.78
LINE
Brooklyn Nets -8.0
1.95
Atlanta Hawks +8.0
1.89
TOTAL POINTS
Over 227.0
1.91
Under 227.0
1.91
```

My problem is there is hidden text under accordions. see screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPMd.png)

-for example i cant scrape the data under the heading 'Double Result"

Once it is 'clicked' the script works fine.

I have written some script that automates the click of the accordion, but unfortunatly the xpath name changes with every match.

does anyone know how to automate clicking all accordions at once (without knowing the element info), or does anyone have a alternative solution.

Any help is welcomed, Thanks

UPDATE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


chrome_path =r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"

d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
d.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NCAA-March-Madness")

time.sleep(2)

d.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/sport-competition-component/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/event-list/div[1]/event/div/header/div[1]/h2/a""").click()
time.sleep(2)

expandable = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h2.accordion-toggle.event-name")))
expandables = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.h2.accordion-toggle.event-name')
for item in expandables:
    item.click()


posts = d.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    with open('output.xls',mode ='a') as f:
        f.write(post.text)
        f.write('\n')

d.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Python test\points1 - Copy.py", line 21, in <module>
    item.click()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a css class selector to grab the collection of dropdowns and click them by iterating over collection. Example page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NBA/58738")
expandable = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h2.accordion-toggle.event-name")))
expandables = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.h2.accordion-toggle.event-name')
for item in expandables:
    item.click()
```

Comment: QHarr, this helped me a lot. I am using the same code for a differnt page under the same website. however the expandable element above does not seem to be clickable. How did you obtain the CSS_selector?

Comment: select the element on the page > right click inspect > then right click on element copy selector. Though I am used to reading css so I usually determine the selector I want by looking at the html. Copy selector can give longer paths than are really necessary. You want a short selector where possible and use id or class where possible.

Comment: is there any reason why the expandable would no longer be interactable?

Comment: I have added the Updated Code and the error thats appearing within the Question.